# What is the proper way to set BPM in Tone.js

Tags: tonejs

I have tried simply setting `Tone.Transport.bpm` but it is ignored. My content just plays at the default 120 BPM. I then looked at [some of the docs](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/Transport.html#constructor) [and it implies](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/Transport) you can pass parameters to a constructor to make a Transport with custom parameters. However when I try this is tells me `Transport is not a constructor`, which I guess it isn't in v14 :/

I am using v14 / Ubuntu / Version 104.0.5112.79 (Official Build) (64-bit) in the latest React.

Here is my code, it is very close to their official example code. The interesting (and confusing!) thing is un-commenting the `rampTo` line does change the tempo, but over the course of 200ms. Setting this value too low causes an error and I don't want the Tempo to shift once playback is started. I want it to start at a set tempo from sample 0...

```js
    import React, {useState} from 'react'
    import * as Tone from 'tone'

    function App() {

        const [toneStarted, setToneStarted] = useState(false)
        const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false)
        const [setup, setSetup] = useState(false)

        async function goHandler(event) {
            if(!toneStarted) await Tone.start()
            setToneStarted(true)
            setPlaying(!playing)
            if(playing) return Tone.Transport.stop()
            
            if(!setup){
                var kick = new Tone.Player("/samples/Kicks/003.WAV").toDestination()
                var snare = new Tone.Player("/samples/Snares/003.WAV").toDestination()
                await Tone.loaded()

                // play a note every quarter-note
                new Tone.Loop(time => {
                    kick.start(time)
                }, "4n").start(0)

                // play another note every off quarter-note, by starting it "8n"
                new Tone.Loop(time => {
                    snare.start(time)
                }, "4n").start("8n")

                // Tone.Transport.bpm.rampTo(50, 0.2);
                setSetup(true)
            }
        
            Tone.Transport.bmp = 50;
            Tone.Transport.start()
        }

        return (
                <div className="App">
                    <header className="App-header">
                        <button onClick={goHandler}>{playing ? "STOP" : "PLAY"}</button>
                    </header>
                </div>
        );
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `.value` notation at the end:

```js
Tone.Transport.bpm.value = 50
```

---

and you got a wrong typo = `bpm` instead of `bmp`

Comment: What about already stored notes? Let's say I have a piano player who played a part, so I cannot quantize to keep it natural. so store ticks for time (note start) and duration also in ticks? then a bpm change would require to update both values for every note in every track?  Guess that's something to pay attention to unless only working with 8n, 16n etc... any best practices please?